# Elasticsearch match partial text in Java

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I have field in elasticsearch "name" which contains for example:
"some text"
I would like to do query which match any partial of this text, for example "some", "so" or "xt"

I was trying do this by `queryString`:

```
public Page<View> search(String name, Pageable pageable) {
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = buildQueryFrom(name);
    HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = buildHighlig();

    SearchRequestBuilder searchRequest = client.prepareSearch()
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)
            .highlighter(highlightBuilder)
            .setFetchSource(null, new String[]{CV_OCR});
    addPageable(searchRequest, pageable);

    SearchResponse response = searchRequest.execute().actionGet();
    return mapper.mapResponse(response, pageable).map(this::View);
}

private QueryBuilder buildQueryFrom(String text) {
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery();

    queryBuilder.must(queryStringQuery("*" + text + "*").field("name"));
    return queryBuilder;
}
```

but if I try to search for example "%" or another special character the results are different than my expectations. I was trying also use regex:

```
private QueryBuilder buildQueryFrom(String text) {
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery();

    queryBuilder.must(regexpQuery("name", quoteStringAndSetCaseInsensitive(text).pattern()));
    return queryBuilder;
}

private Pattern quoteStringAndSetCaseInsensitive(String value) {
    return Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(value), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
}
```

but it didn't work. Is there any other possibility for searching like this?

Comment: Could you show me the pattern? Probably, the problem is in the pattern not in the query.